# Need Help Inserting Delay Between Sound Effect Playback

Tags: javascript, android

I'm still new to Android dev and am stuck.  I have an onTouchEvent that powers a rotating graphic and increases a background int [counter] which triggers a short sound effect (beep) to be played.  Currently, if [counter] > 10 a the sound is played (using the soundpool) and is summarily looped as long as the onTouchEvent keeps counter > 10.  Is it possible to insert a delay between playbacks of the beep sound effect so that the delay decreases the larger the value of [counter] gets?

Example:
if (counter == 10) { delay = 80 // in MS }
if (counter == 90) { delay = 10 // in MS }

My Code:

```
sm = new SoundManager();
    sm.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    sm.addSound(1, R.raw.beep);

...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (buttonClicked) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            counter++;
            startRotating();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            counter--;
            stopRotating();
            break;
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void startRotating() {
    returnRotating = false;

    if (!keepRotating) {
        keepRotating = true;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (keepRotating) {
                    degrees = (degrees + 10) % 360;
                    make(degrees);
                    counter = counter + 1;

                    if (counter > 10)
                        sm.playSound(1);  // plays beep

                    handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added code

```
public void stopRotating() {
    keepRotating = false;

    if (!returnRotating) {
        returnRotating = true;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (returnRotating) {
                    degrees = (degrees - 10) % 360;
                    make(degrees);
                    counter = counter - 1;

                    if (counter > 10) {
                    sm.playSound(1); // plays beep

                    handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
  if (counter > 10) {
      sm.playSound(1);  // plays beep 
      INTERVAL = 100 - counter;
      handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
```

Comment: That's so simple it's brilliant. I'll try that out and update.

Comment: Actually, adjusting INTERVAL causes the fluid motion of the rotation to become choppy so this does not seem to be a good solution.

Comment: That's odd.  All you're doing is changing the delay before you kick off the sound handler again.  There is no additional overhead on the OS if interval is 500ms or 200ms.  It would only become an issue if your loop was really tight.  Are you using INTERVAL anywhere else?  Try putting some log.D calls in with time?

Comment: I updated the code above to include the stop rotating portion where INTERVAL is also called.

Comment: Ah, got it.  So use this instead - handler.postDelayed(this,100-counter);